# SVN + HTTPS = Could not read status line: connection was closed by server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, svn, http, timeout

I have a problem with svn related with https, but with http it works. Here is the problem:

I can Checkout a repo in our SVN-Server, but I can´t commit it, I get following error:

Commit
 Commit failed (details follow):
 OPTIONS of
 'https://svn.example.com/svn/repo-name/trunk/dirname/':
 Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (https://svn.example.com)

So I set the Loglevel higher an I found following message in the apache log:

[Thu Aug 04 14:16:54 2011] [info] [client 123.456.789.10] (70007)The timeout specified has expired:  SSL input filter read failed.
 [Thu Aug 04 14:16:54 2011] [info] [client 123.456.789.10] Connection closed to child 9 with standard shutdown (server svn.example.com:443)

The strange thing is, sometimes it works and the most time not. I use the svn-client tortoise.

Somebody have an idea where the problem is? At google I did not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the mod reqtimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache Timeout value.  Depending on your OS, usually one of these two will work:

`grep -r Timeout /etc/httpd`

or `grep -r Timeout /etc/apache2`